# In 3 level JqGrid, get the first table's primary key when the 2nd table's "+" sign is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcjqgrid

I am new to JqGrid and please help me with this request.

I have a 3 level hierarchical JqGrid setting as shown in the [link](http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/hierarchythreelevels). It is not exactly the same, but very similar. My requirement is to have the `CustomerGrid`'s primary key also passed when `OrderGrid` is expanded.

Or in short, I would like to have

```
    public void SetUpThreeLevelGrids(ThreeLevelHierarchyJqGridModel model)
    {
        var customersGrid = model.CustomersGrid;

        // code here

        int cId;
        //cId = <CustomerId from the CustomerGrid>; //*****How to get this******
        ordersGrid.DataUrl = Url.Action("ThreeLevel_OrdersDataRequested", new { customerId =  cId });

        // code here
    }
```

I would like to use that variable passed to the `ThreeLevel_OrderDetailsDataRequested` method:

```
public JsonResult ThreeLevel_OrderDetailsDataRequested(int customerId, string parentRowID)
{
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a static variable named CustomerId in my Controller. I do not know whether this can break anything or not. I just wanted to make it work.

```
public static int customerId = 0;
```

In the Action method for the second grid, I assigned the CustomerId value.

```
public JsonResult ThreeLevel_OrdersDataRequested(string parentRowID)
{
    var northWindModel = new NorthwindDataContext();
    var model = new ThreeLevelHierarchyJqGridModel();
    customerId = int.Parse(parentRowID);
    SetUpThreeLevelGrids(model);

    //code
}
```

Accessed the global static variable in the third level grid.

```
public JsonResult ThreeLevel_OrderDetailsDataRequested(string parentRowID)
{    
    //Code
    var orderDetails = from o in myDbModel.MyCustomerOrderDetails
         where o.OrderID == Convert.ToInt32(parentRowID)
         and o.CustomerId == customerId //static global variable
         select o;

    //Code
}
```

If anyone has a better suggestion to get the 1st level table's selected primary key in the third level grid, please let me know.